# (CSS) Ways to bind element to bottom?

Tags: html, css, renderer

Is there a other way to put an HTML element to the bottom except :

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

and at the parent element:

```
position: relative
```

...or setting the margin so that the element fits exactly at the bottom?

Comment: Note that in the comments to answer below, OP reveals that the context for this is  for a native-application HTML rendering framework that claims  "Extensive HTML 4.01 and CSS level 2 specifications support". So this is not an html5 or css3 question (as it is currently tagged). It's not even for a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can also use `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`, which will stick the element to the bottom of the window. That means it won't even scroll with the rest of the page.

When you use that for a full-width footer or the like (the most likely use case), you'd then need to add a margin to the rest of the page content so that it doesn't get hidden behind (or hide) the footer.

Other than that you're pretty much stuck with the options you mentioned.

Full documentation on the `position` property can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `position: fixed`

```
.elem {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Or you can use `Flex` then set your element to `align-self: flex-end`

e.g.

```
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.container div {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skt7ezxe/)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortuanetly your second solution did not work... The problem with the "position:fixed" variant is that I am not able to use the position attribute because the HTML renderer hasn't implemented it.

Comment: This does directly answer your question (as does my answer). What sort of "HTML renderer" hasn't implemented `position`? It doesn't sound like your question should be tagged `html5` or `css3` because clearly your circumstances prevent you from using either in any reasonable fashion.

Comment: I'm using this one:  https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com. You can basically add styles to the html but the attribute "position" isn't recognized. That's why I need to find a solution which bypasses it.

Comment: @GreeceTom Aha! "Extensive HTML 4.01 and CSS level 2 specifications support." So I was right about those `html5` and `css3` tags. :) For the sake of posterity (and to avoid getting more answers suggesting CSS3 styles such as `display:flex`) maybe you should edit your question to just have `html` and `css` tags. And since that html renderer package is designed for integrating HTML into a regular application window, it's not too surprising that `position` isn't supported.

Comment: I suppose you'd need to put the HTML block you want to have at the bottom, into a separate `HtmlPanel` (or `HtmlLabel`?)--and then use regular .NET GUI layout practices to position it relative to your other content.